# Laravel : Undefined variable in blade?

Tags: php, laravel

In am getting Undefined variable: score (View: C:\Users\Sarthak\blog\resources\views\submitquestion.blade.php) in blade view when executing :

Controller part

```
public function question(Request $request)
{
    static $startscore = 0;
    $getidvalue = Input::get('getid');
    $getanswervalue = Input::get('getanswer');
    $dbscore = DB::table('5question')->select('question_id', 'correct_answer', 'question_marks')->where('question_id', '=', $getidvalue)->get();
    foreach($dbscore as $value) {
        if ($getanswervalue == ($value->correct_answer)) {
            $getscore = $startscore + $value->question_marks;
        }
        elseif ($getanswervalue == null) {
            $emptyvalue = - 1;
            $getscore = $startscore + $emptyvalue;
        }
        else {
            $novalue = 0;
            $getscore = $startscore + $novalue;
        }
    }

    echo "$getscore";
    Session::push('getscoresession', $getscore);
    $getsession = ['qid' => $getidvalue, 'answer' => $getanswervalue];
    Session::push('answer', $getsession);

    // return response()->json(['qid'=>$getidvalue,'answer'=>$getanswervalue]);

    $score = array_sum(Session::get("getscoresession"));

    // return view('submitquestion',compact('score'));

    return view('submitquestion', ['score' => $score]);
}
```

Blade part :

You have submitted quiz and your score is : {{ $score  }}>



LOGOUT

Comment: In the blade file, use @{{$score}}, instead of  {{ $score }}

Comment: it worked but my value doesn't pass from controller to view... it shows

Comment: You have submitted quiz and your score is : {{ $score }}
>
LOGOUT

Comment: You have used $score as your variable name when passing the data to the view. This results in blade creating a variable called $$score

Comment: i have to pass my session array value in variable and then passes it to blade part how i can proceed ?

Comment: once empty your blade file and add some HTML to check that you are on the proper path.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
return view('submitquestion', compact('score'));
```

Comment: sorry but i am new larave...but still i try this also it shows undefined my problem is that how can i show my score variable in blade part?                                                               <h5>You have submitted quiz and your score is :   {{ $score  }}   </h5>

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass variable form controller to view using **with** and **compact**:

```
$request->session()->put('getscoresession', $getscore);
$getsession = ['qid' => $getidvalue, 'answer' => $getanswervalue];
$request->session()->put('answer', $getsession);

if ($request->session()->has('getscoresession')) {
     $score = array_sum($request->session()->get("getscoresession"));
}else{
      $score = 0;
 }
```

> using with :

```
$score= 10;  
return view('submitquestion')->with('score',$score);
```

> using compact :

```
return view('submitquestion',compact('score'));
```

Comment: how can i get that variable in blade part?

Comment: <p>{{ $score }}</p>

Comment: sorry but i still shows Undefined variable: score (View: C:\Users\Prasoon\blog\resources\views\submitquestion.blade.php).....                             as my score showing in console part but not in blade

Comment: try to pass a static value like $score =10 ; and print it

Comment: then check , you are getting value from Db or not using dd($score);

Comment: sorry but nothing happen?

Comment: i am getting session array in that variable i have to define him any where? in controller

Comment: @prasoonmudgal , please accept and upvote answer , if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. If you get error from your controller send $score = 10; 
return view('submitquestion')->with(['score' => $score]);